# Performance Testing tool for win & web applications

Tags: performance, web-application, windows, sap

My team is looking for a performance testing tool that can work on both Win&Web application. Our application contains an SAP 3D Viewer inside.
We are considering Borland Silk Perfomer & HP Load Runner.

Does anyone know any tool that can fit our spec? And what is the price of those tools?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use Load runner.

Comment: Could you please specify exactly what application part do you want to test with performance testing? What architecture is involved? Is it client-server one?

Comment: @Quang Huy Tiêu, Can you clarify your requirement. What type of Windows app (WPF, WinForms, etc.)?

Comment: Our application contains both Win & Web app, but the app have a component that use: [link](http://www.sap.com/solution/lob/r-and-d/software/product-visualization/index.html) plug-in inside. I'm wondering how I can interact with that plugin for the automation & perf. test. For the web app it's asp.net and for the win app it's C#. Both are using the same plugin from SAP and Telerik controls. It's the client - server architecture @Viktor Malyi. We intent to test the per. of the app using big model loading in the SAP plugin

Comment: Also try with AgileLoad, Apache Jmeter or Apica ProxySniffer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have dismissed JMETER already, or if I'm missing anything. If not, you should probably give it a spin, since it's a free alternative to others.

Answer (score 0):

All of the classical big tools, such as Mercury/HP LoadRunner, Silk/Borland/Microfocus Performer & Rational/IBM Performance Tester all have strong client-server testing backgrounds.  Most of these tools began in the two tier client-server arena and support collection (recording) or development in dozens (in once case over 30) difference interfaces.

LoadRunner historically has been the technically strongest tool in this set, supporting the largest number and types of interfaces, followed by Borland/Microfocus and IBM.  There was a note above asking about architecture of the add ins and this is key.  Understanding what is the next upstream server component and how the widget communicates is critical.  You may even have to mix protocols/interfaces in a single piece of test code and you will need a tool which supports them all.